I couldn't save data in database while using quartz and twilio for sms and email reminder settings in dot net core
I couldn't save data in database while using quartz and twilio for sms and email reminder settings in dot net core.I have done migration and the tables necessary for saving data is also created.The saving api is returning 200 ok and no error can be find inside it. How can i fix it . Is there any need to add any script in database for saving data?
I set sms and email reminder. The sms save api is working perfectly and data succesfully saved message is also showing. but the data is not saved in the databas tables under quartz.
